# Always responding nginx index after deploy angular

Tags: docker, nginx, dockerfile

I am new to Docker. 
I am just starting do some testing after learning tutorial.
I have a test folder contain angular project and Dockerfile

```
test 
|__angular-docker 
|__Dockerfile
```

Docker file configuration is:

```
FROM node:8.11.3-alpine as builder

COPY angular-docker /angular-docker

WORKDIR /angular-docker

RUN npm install
RUN $(npm bin)/ng build

FROM nginx

COPY --from=builder /angular-docker/dist/* /usr/share/ngnix/html/

EXPOSE 80
```

Then I run some command 
Step-1: `~/test$ docker build  -t angular-docker .` (create images) Everything is successful. (create image) 
Step-2: `~/test$ docker run -d --name demo1 -t -p 8080:80 angular-docker` create container

Whenever I access to http://localhost:8080 
it's always responding nginx index.html (default page) but not the angular project. 
Do I miss any configuration or I have configuration mistakes?

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                  NAMES
a9a2a1bb2b36        angular-docker      "nginx -g 'daemon of…"   21 minutes ago      Up 21 minutes       0.0.0.0:8080->80/tcp   demo1
```

Comment: I think you need to setup your `nginx.conf` file

Comment: This nginx.conf file is in server PC?
Can you share the cofiguration or any link?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved the above problem by changing some command:

```
# stage 1
FROM node:8.11.3-alpine as node
WORKDIR /app
COPY . .
RUN npm install
RUN npm run build --prod

# stage 2
FROM nginx:alpine
COPY --from=node /app/dist/angular-docker /usr/share/nginx/html
```

Answer (score 0):

You should set nginx  index parameter to serve your index html file in nginx config.
you have two index in "/usr/share/ngnix/html/" same time

```
index index.html index.htm;
```